# Spring Data CRUD Method Name for: Child Object IN

Tags: spring, spring-data

I have a `UserRoles (USER_ROLES_T)` domain object which contains a `Lookup` child object which is an ID.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER_ROLES_T")
public class UserRoles {
   //...
   private LookupT role;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "LOOKUP_T") {
public class LookupT {
  //...
  private int id;
}
```

I need to run a Spring Data CRUD method (no annotations) whose name would find by **role (LookupT) IN (List).**

E.g.:

`findUserRolesByRoleIdIn(List<Integer> roleIds);`

`findUserRolesByRoleIdIn(100,101);`

But would this be correct? I'm not referencing a flat field called `roleId`. I need to find by `role.id in (..)`. So what's the correct Spring Data CRUD signature to denote the child object's IN?

Comment: Why would adding annotations (such as `@Query`) be considered bad?

Comment: `@Query` doesn't allow me to use constants. Therefore I decided to use Derived Query Names, since I need to use a list of constants (that I can now pass from the service method). Hence the `roleIds in ...`.